# Translate code to laravel blade

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

My condition in view blade cause I ussually used native php coding :

> $jlhkriteria = Kriteria::count();
>
> kriterias table : id_kriteria, kriteria_name

```
@for ($i = 1; $i <= $jlhkriteria; $i ++)
    <?php $queri1 = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM kriterias WHERE id_kriteria='$i' ORDER BY id_kriteria ASC");
    $kriteria1 = mysqli_fetch_array($queri1, MYSQLI_ASSOC); ?>

    @for ($j = $i + 1; $j <= $jlhkriteria ; $j ++)

    <?php $queri2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM kriterias WHERE id_kriteria='$j' ORDER BY id_kriteria ASC");
            $kriteria2 = mysqli_fetch_array($queri2, MYSQLI_ASSOC); ?>



    <?php echo $i . $j; ?>

<?php echo $kriteria1['kriteria_name']; ?>
<?php echo $kriteria2['kriteria_name']; ?>
@endfor
@endfor
```

In Laravel 5 I used this code because I think query in View are bad ideas, any ideas to make this in MVC like without query it in Blade view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create model and controller classes that contain your business logic then pass the data to a view. Something similar to that:

Model:

```
class Kriteria extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'kriterias';
}
```

Controller:

```
class KriteriaController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $kriteria = Kriteria::orderBy('id_kriteria')->get();
        return view('index', compact('kriteria'));
    }
}
```

View:

```
@for($i=0; $i < count($kriteria); $i ++)
    @for($j = $i + 1; $j < count($kriteria) ; $j ++)
        {{ $i . $j }}
        {{$kriteria[$i]->kriteria_name.' '.$kriteria[$j]->kriteria_name}}
    @endfor
@endfor
```

Comment: kriteria1['kriteria_name'] and kriteria2['kriteria_name'] cant be echo (updated question, sorry I forgot to add details about it. that's why I put mysqli fetch array between for)

Comment: You can echo them like {{`$kriteria[$i]->kriteria_name`}} and {{`$kriteria[$j]->kriteria_name}}`

Comment: I got error exception on undefined offset: 3, where 'kriteria' => object(Collection), probably because in return view('index', compact('kriteria')] -- where is the opening " [ "

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the typo, I edited the answer. Also try to double check your `$i` and `$j` variables in the for loop.

Comment: okay it Solved, it's because $i = 0; $i <, while in my question is $i = 1;$i <=, so i just modified {{ $i . $j }} to {{ $i+1 . $j+1 }}, Thank You.

Comment: one more question what if my "$queri1 = select joined 2 table where id_kriteria = $i" how to echo kriteria ?

Comment: Then you will need to have 2 queries, one for the join and another for the select. I recommend implementing the join query in the model as class method, then call it from the controller and put the output in a different variable. but I think that's a different question.